# Google Cloud Functions authentication to other GCP APIs

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to write a Google Cloud Function that can interact with GCP's Dataproc service to programatically launch Dataproc clusters. We already have a battle-hardened Dataproc infrastructure, we're just looking to extend the ways in which they get launched.

Our Dataproc clusters can only be launched using an appropriate IAM service account that is already a member of the appropriate IAM roles hence the Cloud Function will need to authenticate to the Dataproc service using that service account. What is the most appropriate way for a Cloud Function to authenticate to other GCP services/APIs using a service account?

Options I suspect include:
* running the function as that service account
* providing a JSON key file & setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable

Is there a recognised way of achieving this?

I have had a look at :
* https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
* https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
but they are not specific to Cloud Functions.

I've also looked at
* https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http
but that seems more concerned with how the caller of the function can authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam

> At runtime, Cloud Functions defaults to using the App Engine default service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), which has the Editor role on the project. You can change the roles of this service account to limit or extend the permissions for your running functions. You can also change which service account is used by providing a non-default service account on a per-function basis.

tl;dr `gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

By the way, if you ever need more complex scheduling logic, consider looking into Cloud Composer (managed Apache Airflow): https://cloud.google.com/composer/